# Using Topo to Raster tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, lock, anudem

I am trying to make a DEM using topo to raster tool. When it is done a message pops up that some drawings Cannot acquire a lock, and the DEM is not visible. I have made a DEM before with the same data and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Close ArcMap and used Task Manager to end all ArcGIS-related processes (ArcGISCacheMgr.exe and ArcGISConnection.exe). Check by adding the output rasters if rendered with no drawing errors in a new MXD as well as in the original MXD.

Comment: The "Cannot acquire a lock" error usually means some other process still has control of that file. Thus why @Yogi recommends closing all ArcGIS-related processes. You might also want to double check that there aren't any other non-ArcGIS topo/DEM software processes working on these files too.

Comment: @ycartwhelen, thank you:)